# Suppose △ K L T ≅ △ T K L . Name the non-identical congruent segments and angles. What kind of triangle is △ K L T?

Tags: geometry

I am having troubles with problem. I need clarification.

Suppose △ K L T ≅ △ T K L .
Name the non-identical congruent segments and angles.

The congruent segments are KL=TK, KT=TL, and LT=KL.

The congruent angles were <L = <K and <T = < L.

What kind of triangle is △ K L T ?

The triangle is an isosceles.

Comment: A similarity statement is often not that strict in normal use, so you don't necessarily name the vertices in matching order. But assuming that's what you are doing here, the matching  implies equilateral to me.

Comment: Oh. I see. That makes sense. Thank you.